# htaccess - Exclude admin folder rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in my htaccess file I have this code:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
>
> #RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1
> #RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)$ ./members.php?name=$1
>
> #RewriteBase /www.embellez.com/
>
> #INGLES
> RewriteRule ^en/listagem/(\w+)$ ./en/listagem.php?c=$1
> RewriteRule ^en/listagem/(\w+)/$ ./en/listagem.php?c=$1
> RewriteRule ^en/detalhe/(\w+)/(\w+)$ ./en/detalhe.php?c=$1&id=$2
> RewriteRule ^en/detalhe/(\w+)/(\w+)/$ ./en/detalhe.php?c=$1&id=$2
> ```

what is in the code above, allows you to use friendly URLs. What I want now is to not use url's friendlies, ie no rules to access the pages in a given folder (./admin). Ie, the rules will become meaningless in this folder (./admin).

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Did you just want that admin folder is not access by others or wanted that htacess not change the url of admin folders

Comment: wanted that htacess not change the url of admin folders :)